# Postfix relaying emails to another domain

Tags: postfix-mta

I have configured postfix over SSL and dovecot over SSL and it work fine if I send local relay , and it delivers to mailboxes within my domain name MX record point mail server.

mysysopmnds.com  MX 10 mail.mysysopminds.com

However if I send an email to another domain , it bounces... and one of the error in the log is , as below

Jan 10 19:34:56 mail postfix/smtp[5334]: 37FADC28BB: to=, relay=none, delay=34, delays=34/0/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for murugeshdomain.com loops back to myself)

what are key configuration that I should check or take care of to send email to other domains or any domains

TIA

hariharan

Answer (score 1):

The is a good chance your internet serivice provider (ISP) is blocking out port 25 for outgoing email. I can tell you, mine is. This is also when i got the bounce message.
You can confirm this problem by typing:

```
telnet aspmx.l.google.com 25
```

If it does not generate **Connected to aspmx.l.google.com** but a timeout after half a minute or so than your ISP is blocking your outgoing traffic on port 25.
If this is the case you can solve it by redirecting your outgoing mail through for example a google mail account. You could use [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228938/how-can-i-configure-postfix-to-send-all-email-through-my-gmail-account) as guide to set the up the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this domain (murugeshdomain.com) has no MX record. For sending mails to another domain just take look in that domain has MX record. To check whether that domain has MX record  dig MX domainname(in the case of linux command)

Comment: Hi,dig command output on the mail server host resolves to MX ;; QUESTION SECTION:
;murugeshdomain.com.            IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
murugeshdomain.com.     86400   IN      MX      10 mail.murugeshdomain.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
murugeshdomain.com.     86400   IN      NS      ns.murugeshdomain.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.murugeshdomain.com. 86400  IN      A       10.0.0.6

;; Query time: 9 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.12#53(10.0.0.12)
;; WHEN: Fri Jan 10 19:58:35 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104

Comment: any thoughts , anyone ?

Comment: @user173639 can you resolve the murugeshdomain.com? In my system it will not resolve. Please try dig MX +short murugeshdomain.com, and see if it will resolve or not.